# MovieClip(root.this) not working

Tags: actionscript-3, this, root

I'm having a issue in AS3 with using MovieClip(root.this).
So I have a MovieClip called Slime and I have code inside of slime.idle in the 1rst frame. The code is:  MovieClip(root.this).gotoAndStop(2);

For some reason that will not work and does not make the slime go to frame 2. I don't want to do MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(2); because I have more than 1 slime in the stage that I do not want all of them going to frame 2. That is why I need to use MovieClip(root.this). Does anyone know my problem and how to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MovieClip(root.this)` is not valid syntax for multiple reasons. I don't think `this` behaves how you think; [`this` refers to the object that the script belongs to](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#this) and cannot be used the way you are trying to use it.

Are you trying to target a specific "slime" to go to frame 2 within its own timeline? In that case you just need to call `gotoAndStop()` on a reference to that specific slime. For example: `MovieClip(root).slime123.gotoAndStop(2)`. How you get the reference depends on your current code and display structure.

If your code is within the "slime" symbol timeline, you can make it go to frame 2 without referring to `root` at all, because `this` is already the target you want. For example: `this.gotoAndStop(2)` (or `gotoAndStop(2)`; `this` is usually optional).

If you post more code and explain what you thought `this` should refer to, I can help more.